# Why Java don't parallize this stream computation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

I have written some code that I believe is likely to throw an exception. But an IDEA Ide #IC-231.8109.175 surprisingly show me warning `Condition 'id != Thread.currentThread().threadId()' is always 'false'`.
I am doubtful about the accuracy of this warning and interested why it really always evaluates to false.

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long id = Thread.currentThread().threadId();
        var g = IntStream.range(0, 100_000_000).boxed()
                .parallel()
                .map(k -> {
                    if (id != Thread.currentThread().threadId()) {
                        throw new RuntimeException();
                    }
                    return k + 1;
                }).findAny();

        System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not throwing the exception because there's no need for parallelism when you're using `findAny()` with no filter. Changing it to `findFirst()` throws an exception but doesn't remove the warning, strangely.

Comment: @shmosel Oops, my mistake, misread the code.

Comment: @Holger Why is there no need to evaluate the mapping function?

Comment: @shmosel my bad, I mixed it up with the logic of `isPresent()`